# HttpContext.User.Claims always empty despite JWT containing claims

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an asp-mvc api that reads the jwt claims on an incoming request, and then mirrors them back to the user - my use case is that I'm trying to investigate why a different endpoint is failing, I get a token from an external service, so I want minimal/no auth on it, I just want to inspect the claims.

I have the following Controller and endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testclaims")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string?>> TestClaims()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var claim in HttpContext.User.Claims)
            result.Add($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");

        return "{ " + String.Join(", ", result.ToArray()) + " }";
    }
}
```

My app is setup like this:

```
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            RequireSignedTokens = false,
            RequireAudience = false,
            SaveSigninToken = false,
            TryAllIssuerSigningKeys = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
    };
        builder.Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options);
    });

    var app = builder.Build(); 
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
```

I'm calling the endpoint from postman I make a request with an auth token containing a know set of claims, `HttpContext.User.Claims` is always empty, but I can see `HttpContext.Request.Headers` contains the expected token, and if I decode that externally, it contains the claims.

I've tried adding an Authorize decorator to the endpoint, but when I do I get a 401 returned with no log or debug info.

I'm assuming there's just something I need to enable to have asp populate the claims?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `[Authorize]`.

Besides, you miss the `app.UseAuthentication();` before your `app.UseAuthorization();`.

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

result:
[image]
Have a try, hope it can help you.

Comment: If I add both of those, I get a 401 returned, but I don't get any useful logs to explain why it's not authorized.

a) is there a way to get that debug
b) is there a way to configure auth to just accept all jwts

Comment: To be clear, as this is likely where the auth error is coming from - the token I'm submitting is coming from a different program than this application.  The token is issued by our identity provider, this program is just a microservice in that setup

Comment:  - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)